# grep in "match" mode or another command?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a text input like this:

```
TOKEN=32141234134143
ERROR=this is an error
```

The above two line will not occur at the same time.  i.e. either TOKEN or ERROR but not both.

I use `grep` on the above input like this:

```
cat input |grep TOKEN
```

If there are error, the output will be nothing. What I want is that no matter what the text is, grep only match for the regex but **not** filter the text, if match is not found grep simply returns an non-zero exit code.

Is that possible, or any other command line tool to do this?

**EDIT**: I want the output of grep to be **ALL** input text, including non-matching linese, **not** NONE text, which the `-q` option of grep gives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`ack`](https://beyondgrep.com/) (using *pass-through* mode):

```
ack --passthru TOKEN input
```

or, depending on your distro

```
ack-grep --passthru --color TOKEN input
```

will print the whole input, highlight the matches and exit `1` if no match is found (and `0` if found).

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
grep -q TOKEN file && cat file
```

The `-q` of `grep` is *quiet* mode.  If the pattern is found, `cat` outputs the full contents of the file.

Comment: This is NOT what I want. I want the grep command to **NOT** filter text. i.e. whatever text it go through, it should output ALL text, including those not matching!

Comment: @xrfang Consider the updated answer.

Comment: @Kusalanda this does not work, or is awkward. becasue I am actually piping a serie of commands and using the `jq` tool to parse json output, blah blah...

Comment: @xrfang If you want to clarify the question, then do so by editing the question. Note that most of the parsing, including tho test that `grep` or `ack` would be carrying out, can most likely be done by `jq` too, but you never show any JSON document...  Also note that I was not notified of your comment due to you spelling my name wrong (I saw it by chance).

Comment: @Kusalananda sorry for the typo.  I do not want to explain my usage of `jq`, which might be suitable for another question.   I may well use `tee` like this:  command|tee /dev/tty|grep -q TOKEN,  but anyway I just want to know what I asked in the question. thanks.

Comment: @xrfang Writing directly to the TTY could work in this case but is in general not a good option as it stops you from using your script from, e.g., a cron job (has no TTY associated), and it also makes it very awkward to redirect the output of the script elsewhere.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks for the comment on cronjob.   I am writing shell script for Makefile, but if I want to use it in cronjob, what do you think is the problem with the accepted answer -- `ack` ?

Comment: @xrfang There is no problem at all with the accepted answer other than requiring a non-standard tool, while this answer does not require anything special. This comment thread is mostly about having corrected the initially (clearly) incorrect answer, not about how it should be the accepted answer (although I personally would do it this way).

Comment: @Kusalananda the reason I want the output is because that the command line tool is expected to be used **interactively**, i.e. the user will need to know the feedback immediately,  in case of error.  If I would use it in a cronjob, maybe I can `tee` the output to a file instead of tty.